# Need Mobile Safari to run a java script while my iPhone is in sleep-mode

Tags: javascript, ios, web-applications, safari

Recently I submitted an iPhone app that was rejected because it uses the APNS to push messages that could contain marketing and advertising information. Because of this, I now need to create a web app instead of a native phone app.

My problem is that I need to poll the phone’s location in the background. When Safari is in sleep mode I need to somehow have a java script running in the background to monitor location changes. Has anyone been able to do this?

Comment: What you're looking to do is explicitly blocked to improve battery life. I suggest you find another path.

Comment: Thanks for answering. Can you suggest what that path might be? I'm out of ideas.

Comment: Specifically? No. Generally? You'd have to tell us more about what your business objective is.

Comment: Ok, I'd like to send messages to an iPhone when it is in a specific location. If the phone is in sleep-mode, I'd like the web app to be able to send a message to the phone. The message is probably not advertising and marketing but I will not be able to control it so I won't no for sure. Is that what you mean by 'business objective'?

Comment: Sort of. What will the phone do with the message once it's received it? Regardless, if you want to take an action on the phone based on an external event, you'll need a native app. Even then, your options are limited (though tricks like [background location notification](http://www.tomjstokes.com/130/iphone-ios-4-2-background-location-service-observations) may help). It does sound like push notifications may be your best option. How about addressing Apple's concerns about the notifications you're sending?

Comment: The phone will notify the user of the message with an icon badge and an alert message. My app was lovely when it used native Push Notifications but since the actual messages are out of my hands, I need to find another alternative. I would love to address Apple's concerns with a promise regarding the content of the messages but that's not in line with the purpose of the app.